# How to make Webmin SpamAssassin less sensitive?

Tags: postfix-mta, webmin, spamassassin

It's odd that even emails from SPFBL Admin  are marked as spam. Im using Webmin, with Postfix and SpamAssassin. Is my SpamAssassin too sensitive?

Comment: You can go to webmin SpamAssassin mail filter and explore the various ways you can adjust the sensitivity. I usually play around with the settings until i get my desired result. the following link will give you a good idea https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SpamAssassin_Mail_Filter

Comment: Yeah I saw that. But not sure how to play around with it

Comment: Change your default conviction score from 5 to 8.5 (`required_score 8.5` in `local.cf`) and consider purging your Bayes and AWL databases if you use them (and you should absolutely use Bayes), see [Bayes Not Working](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/BayesNotWorking). I can't comment on using Webmin for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know how to configure, I advise you to use zoho is a tool where you can create Your administrative email.

but in this case you will not be able to redirect for example to a Gmail box

Be sure to send your feedback

Comment: Just signed-up on Zoho, but got a blank page in Mail section -> https://nimb.ws/CgGahI

Comment: But must I move ALL my domain email addresses to use Zoho? So, all john@ mike@ info@ must use Zoho? Like changing MX records for entire domain email handling?

Comment: Ah .. yes ... It is limited ... So for each domain account you must create an account.

Comment: Limited meaning? So i must create SEPARATE zoho accounts for each email like john@mysite.com  = 1 zoho acc, and tim@mysite.com another zoho acc?

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is according to your criteria and yes your customers they will have to access Zoho. This can be a temporary measure until you set up your definitive one. But I like Zoho a lot. Even more so that it has other add-ons.

The good thing about it is that people can log in, through their Google account. So you put the Google address as a user of that email and automatically when it authenticates via the interface it connects exactly to the email